# Next.js compile takes too long after an error

Tags: next.js

I am developing a Next.js app within a docker dev environment as HMR enabled.

After fixing a syntax or module import error, Next.js takes too long to compile (more than a few minutes), accompanied with high CPU usage. Usually what I do is to close the current Chrome tab, which terminates current build cycle, and open application in a new tab. Then, the compile happens much faster.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Man. I know why this is doing it, but I can't explain it too well since I don't know Docker terminology too well

It might be happening because in your yaml file, where you define which files should monitored for changes that trigger a build, the .tsx and .ts files aren't included. So everytime you change one file, docker triggers a rebuild of the whole app, instead of just rebuilding that small file

Take a look at this example code that I use. This can explain it a bit better :)

```
 # Employee UI
        - image: app/concept-employee-ui
          context: employee-ui
          docker:
              dockerfile: Dockerfile
          sync:
              manual:
                  - src: "src/**/*.jsx"
                    dest: .
                  - src: "src/**/*.js"
                    dest: .
                  - src: "src/**/*.css"
                    dest: .
                  - src: "src/**/*.scss"
                    dest: .
                  - src: "src/**/*.ts"
                    dest: .
                  - src: "src/**/*.tsx"
                    dest: .
```

Comment: Yes, I mount my local directory to Docker and local file changes syncs with Docker filesystem. However, changing a file doesn't trigger a rebuild of the whole app and it works fine. My problem is when Next.js build fails because of a syntax error, and I fix the error, the next build takes much longer. I doubt this is due to Docker but somehow Next.js being throttled by the HMR requests during rebuild.